# Cannot create my Spring Batch tables in a different schema in Postgres

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-batch, datasource

I have a Spring Boot app that uses Hibernate and Spring Batch. I am using PostgreSQL for my backend database.

My project has 2 different data sources configured: one for Hibernate and one for Spring Batch. They are both in the same database but in different schemas.

My spring batch connection string is the following:

```
spring.batch.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mytestapp?currentSchema=springbatch
```

I have the Datasource configured in the following way:

```
@Bean("b_ds_prop")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.batch.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean("b_ds")
    @DependsOn({"b_ds_prop"})
    public DataSource batchFrameworkDatasource(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
        System.out.println("start print");
//      dataSourceProperties.getSchema().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
//      System.out.println("datasrcprop is null : " + (dataSourceProperties==null));
//      System.out.println("datasrcprop.schema is null : " + (dataSourceProperties.getSchema()==null));
        System.out.println("end print");
//      dataSourceProperties.setSchema(Arrays.asList("spring_batch"));
        return dataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @DependsOn({"b_ds"})
    public BatchConfigurer defaultBatchConfigurer(@Qualifier("b_ds") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource);
    }
```

The `currentSchema=springbatch` setting is not respected, no matter what I do. All my Spring Batch tables keep ending up in `public` in Postgres.

The schema named `springbatch` is already present in my database : `mytestapp`.

I have tried `currentSchema=springbatch, public`, I have even tried `spring.batch.table-prefix=springbatch.`.

I have tried everything, but still I cannot understand why my batch tables keep ending up in the `public` schema.

Note I have another connection string in my project like:

```
spring.hib.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mytestapp
```

I have also tried programmatically checking what is the value of `schema` in `DataSourceProperties`.

```
System.out.println("datasrcprop.schema is null : " + (dataSourceProperties.getSchema()==null));
```

This evaluates to true.

How can I set the schema to be different for Spring Batch ?

Comment: Spring Batch works against a datasource (it does not know about schemas) and does not create tables. Since you created a `BatchConfigurer` and passed the `b_ds` datasource to it, you need to either run the postgres DDL script by hand against that datasource before starting your app, or tell Spring Boot to do it for you (and make sure it will initialize *that* datasource with Spring Batch tables).

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spring boot automatically creates the spring batch metadata tables at starting. It executes the default script which is located in `org.springframework.batch.core` package. In your situtation, this script is `schema-postgresql.sql`. This script creates tables in the postgre default schema so `public` if nothing is specified (and as we don't know which datasource spring boot uses to create spring batch metadata tables, we don't know what is the default schema).

When executing creation script, spring boot doesn't take into account `spring.batch.table-prefix` property which is only used to say spring batch where metadata tables are.

If you want to control this spring boot feature, you should :

- modify the creation script (add the `springbatch` schema) and give spring boot the path for the modified script (`spring.batch.schema` property)

OR

- create by yourself spring batch metadata tables before starting application and disable spring boot auto creation (`spring.batch.initialize-schema=never` property)

Good luck

Comment: I cannot just modify the script once during startup because Spring Batch will not know how to locate it later.

Comment: If you extract the sql script from the spring batch jar, then modify it adding your schema and after save it in the resources folder of your project, it would work wouldn't it ?
Please, keep in mind that Spring batch doesn't need the script. Only Spring boot autoconfiguration feature for spring batch needs it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this configration:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mytestapp

#spring batch properties
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false
spring.batch.initialize-schema=never
spring.batch.table-prefix=springbatch.
```

Comment: Now I have no tables since you have mentioned `spring.batch.initialize-schema=never`. Does not work.